# Adding objects to array on Lua

Tags: lua

First of all I'm new on lua, I'm trying to implement a simple shopping cart as an object oriented exercise.

So I defined a Cart Object which stores several items objects

```
Cart = {
    items = {},
    discount = 0
}

function Cart:new(discount)
    local object = {}
    setmetatable(object, {__index = self})
    self.discount = discount

    return object
end

function Cart:addItem(item)
    table.insert(self.items, item)
end

function Cart:GetTotal()
    local total = 0
    for i = 1, #self.items do
        total = total + self.items[i]:GetPrice()
    end
    return total - self.discount
end
```

Each Item has the responsibility of calculate their price:

```
Item = {
    units = 0,
    pricePerUnit = 5,
    name = ""
}

function Item:new(units, pricePerUnit, name)
    local object = {}
    setmetatable(object, {__index =  self})
    self.units = units
    self.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit
    self.name = name

    return object
end

function Item:GetPrice()
    return self.units * self.pricePerUnit
end
```

But when I create the object and add items I get 60 as result, When I debugged the script I found that all the elements of the table are identical as if they were overwritten, could someone explain to me why and how can it be solved? Thanks in advance.

```
local shoppingCart = Cart:new(0)
shoppingCart:addItem(Item:new(1, 10, "Oranges"))
shoppingCart:addItem(Item:new(1, 15, "lemons"))
shoppingCart:addItem(Item:new(1, 20, "Strawberries"))

print(shoppingCart:GetTotal())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cart:new` and `Item:new` are meant to create new objects, therefore you call them on the classes themselves rather than on instances. That means the `self` that gets passed to those methods is those classes.

In both of those methods, you create an `object` table to become the new object, so you need to set the fields on that object, instead of modifying the class, eg, `object.discount = discount`.

Comment: Thank you! it worked, so when I use self in the "constructor" I am modifying the "prototype" not the instance, however when I use self in the rest of the methods I am modifying the instance, right?

Comment: Yes, but it all depends on how you call it. When calling a method, the expression before the colon gets passed in as the `self` parameter, so `Cart:new(...)` and `shoppingCart:addItem(...)` respectively get `Cart` and `shoppingCart` as `self`.